# Diagnostic plot (residual vs. predicted) of a glmm using DHARMa

Tags: residuals, diagnostic, glmmtmb

I used glmmTMB to fit a model with beta distributed errors, zero inflation, several nested random effects and temporal correlation. I then used the diagnostic plots available in DHARMa. My residual vs predicted plot looks like this [image]
The plot is (I think) similar to the one shown in the other packages section of the DHARMa package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html#other-packages). What is the meaning of the dashed line? Also, are all three residual lines overlapping at 0.50?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that the question has been posed before and answered [here](https://github.com/florianhartig/DHARMa/issues/75)

Quoting Florian Hartig's response:

> Hi, this is expected behavior - the default of the plot function is to
>   do the quantile regression for n <= 2000, and for larger datasets a
>   nonparametric smoother, because the quantile regressions can take a
>   long time to calculate. You can overwrite this if you want. Example
>
> library(DHARMa)
>
> testData = createData(sampleSize = 2200, family = poisson(), 
>                         randomEffectVariance = 0, numGroups = 5) fittedModel <- glm(observedResponse ~ Environment1, 
>                      family = "poisson", data = testData) simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = fittedModel)
>
> plot(simulationOutput) # default switches to quanreg = F for n > 2000 
>   plot(simulationOutput, quantreg = T) # overrule default
>
> side note: with so many data points, and binomial, it would be useful
>   to think about if you can group your data in some way, using the new
>   recalculateResiduals() function in DHARMa 0.2.0

Comment: I am not sure if this should be an answer or an update of the original post. Please advise.

Comment: The answer is still good, just an add-on: there is a new DHARMa version with a more efficient quantile regression available for beta testing, see https://twitter.com/florianhartig/status/1227291704371269632